List (Error) Response size exceeds limit
I'm trying to convert an imagecollection into a one-dimensional list, but I'm getting this error：

One-dimensional NDVI List: List (Error) Response size exceeds limit

How do I calculate the cumulative percentile corresponding to each value?
I tried to do it like this:
function set_year(collection, name) {
  return collection.map(function(img) {
    var year = ee.String(img.get('id_no')).slice(0, 4);
    var img2 = img.select("b1").rename(name);
    return img2.set('year', year);
  });
}

var ndvi = set_year(NDVI, 'ndvi');
print('NDVI with year property:', ndvi);

var filtered_ndvi = ndvi.filter(ee.Filter.rangeContains('year', '2001', '2005'));
print('Filtered NDVI (2001-2005):', filtered_ndvi);

var filtered_ndvi_count = filtered_ndvi.size();
print('Filtered NDVI count:', filtered_ndvi_count);

var filtered_ndvi_list = filtered_ndvi.toList(filtered_ndvi_count);
print('Filtered NDVI List (2001-2005):', filtered_ndvi_list);

var flattened_list = filtered_ndvi_list.map(function(img) {
  var img_obj = ee.Image(img);
  return img_obj.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
    geometry: table,
    scale: 250
  }).get('ndvi');
});

var one_d_list = ee.List(flattened_list).flatten();
print('One-dimensional NDVI List:', one_d_list);


reduceRegion() with ee.Reducer.toList() will not work for any larger number of pixels. Can you describe in more details what you are trying to do?

I need to use all the pixel values ​​of the 5 images in the ImageCollection to get a large image. Then calculate the cumulative percentile corresponding to each value./(ㄒoㄒ)/~~

This is still not clear to me. You want to calculate the percentile for all NDVI pixel values across all years? So a single value coming out from your calculation? If so, you could perhaps create a histogram per year, merge the histograms, then calculate this percentile based on that.

I also don't know what result I should get. I made a mistake above. What I calculated was not a percentage, that is, what I got was not just one value. I wanted to get a corresponding value for each NDVI value. I can accomplish what I want in python: input five years of NDVI values ​​into a large array. Count unique values ​​and sort them from smallest to largest. Counts the number of occurrences of each unique value in the array, and accumulates the occurrences of all values ​​smaller than the current unique value.

For each unique value, count its occurrences plus the occurrences of all values ​​smaller than it, then divide by the total number of pixels and multiply by 100% to get a percentage. Actually what I'm calculating is cumulative frequency percentage. Can GEE accomplish this operation?

If I under stand you correctly, you could estimate the percentile with something like the below. It creates a cumulative histogram for each of your yearly NDVIs, sums up the counts and calculates the percentile based on that. Adjust min and max based on your data range. The steps argument controls the accuracy of your estimation. It's not at all imposible that I haven't made some mistakes in this implementation, but it hopefully gives you an idea on how you can attack your problem.
Note, that if you instead need the percentile for each individual year, you simply reduceRegion() each yearly NDVI with an ee.Reducer.percentile() reducer.
var percentiles = estimatePercentile({
  collection: filtered_ndvi,
  percentiles: [25, 50, 75], 
  scale: 250,
  geometry: geometry,
  min: -0.2,
  max: 1,
  steps: 1000
})

print(percentiles)


function estimatePercentile(args) {
  var collection = args.collection
  var percentiles = args.percentiles
  var geometry = args.geometry
  var scale = args.scale
  var min = args.min
  var max = args.max
  var steps = args.steps
  
  var histograms = ee.Array(ee.List(collection
    .map(function (image) {
      var histogram = ee.Array(image
        .reduceRegion({
          reducer: ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram({
            min: min, 
            max: max, 
            steps: steps, 
            cumulative: true
          }), 
          geometry: geometry, 
          scale: scale, 
          maxPixels: 1e13, 
          tileScale: 16
        })
        .get('NDVI')
      )
      return ee.Feature(null, {histogram: histogram.toList()})
    })
    .aggregate_array('histogram')
  ))
  var values = histograms
    .slice(0, 0, 1)
    .slice(2, 0, 1)
    .project([1, 2])
  var counts = histograms
    .slice(2, 1)
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0])
    .project([1, 2])
  var histogram = ee.Array.cat([values, counts], 1)
  
  var totalCount = histogram.slice(0, -1).slice(1, 1)
  
  return percentiles.map(function (k) {
    var targetCount = totalCount.multiply(k).divide(100)
    var percentileScore = histogram
      .mask(counts.gte(targetCount.repeat(0, histogram.length().get([0]))))
      .get([0, 0])
    return percentileScore    
  })
}

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1fff8096051e8f77d074ef6ed8bd0a27

Thank you！！！！！！！
